# django usercreationform is_valid always return false

Tags: django

i'm green hand to django, when i try to use the usersignupform, the request post is like

```
`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Wxlj42vbyAweKevBeSs5TvGj1ot8tJknUOGzmlKCphs5cDnqvsmriCSK9wYDuAof'], 'username': ['dulong11'], 'email': ['stephen.du@abc.com'], 'password1': ['dulong'], 'password2': ['dulong'], 'submit': ['']}`
```

then the usercreationform.is_valid() will always return false, i do not know why, and how it happens? why it cannot work??

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    #password1 = forms.CharField()
    #password2 = forms.CharField()

     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

view.py i tried to use usersignupform for create a new user, but it just failed, and the form.is_valid() is false

```
form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
print(request.POST)
print(form.is_valid())
```

register.html

```
      <form action="." method="post" id="frm" class="frm">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="r-list">
                <div class="line">
                    <i class="dqfont icon-mobilephone"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="用户名" autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="error" id="tel_error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="r-list">
              <div class="line">
                <i class="dqfont icon-mobilephone"></i>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="请输入邮箱" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            <div class="r-list">
              <div class="line">
                <i class="dqfont icon-pass"></i>
                <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="请输入密码" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <span class="error"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="r-list">
              <div class="line">
                <i class="dqfont icon-pass"></i>
                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="请再次输入你的密码" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <span class="error"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="r-list">
              <div class="protocol">
               <span class="checkbox-checked" id="accept">我已阅读并同意<a href="#" 
     target="_blank">《IPLink用户协议》</a>和<a href="#" target="_blank">《隐私保护》</a></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="r-list">
              <span class="error"></span>
              <!--a href="#" class="btn" id="btn">同意协议并注册</--a>-->
              <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" id="btnSubmit"  
     style="width:380px">同意协议并注册</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Where is your view?

Comment: if a form is not valid, then it has errors, what is `form.errors`?

Comment: configure exception if form is not valid so you can find what is going on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650306/django-raise-forms-validationerror-not-working

Comment: if you want more help you must update your question with `view.py` and `models.py`codes

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>The password is too similar to the username.</li><li>This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.</li></ul></li></ul> problem solved, thank you all. too silly

Answer (score 2):

form.error is like the following. problem solved, too silly, damn~

password2

The password is too similar to the username.

This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.

Comment: you should always **display** the form errors in your template. How are your users supposed to know what's wrong when they fill in the registration form?